# WIN10 - Network drives won't show up

Tags: networking, windows-10, batch

We have one user with a Windows 10 PC who has been encountering an issue with mapped drives. It was working and suddenly it wasn't anymore.

To map network drives we use a batch scripts system. PC is a Windows 10 workstation in our domain.

Script is pretty much basic and looks like :

> net use G: "\SRV\FOLDER" /persistent:no

but for some reason it won't work anymore.

Access from Explorer works, so rights aren't in cause. When we launch script manually, it won't map any drives.

There is this one folder that we set up with a persistent net use : this one shows up, no problem. Our batch script just won't do its work.

One thing that may be of importance : this particular user has a lot of network drives, 12 to be precise. Could it be a problem ? She also is one of the few that runs with Windows 10 Pro, everyone else is Win 7 Pro and don't have this issue.

Any thoughts ? I'd rather avoid doing persistent net use.

Comment: Assuming there isn't a drive letter collision and not knowing if there is any limit, have you tried to disconnect a few shares and running the script?

And IMHO, mapped drives are a very bad idea. I'll have nightmares with a "crypto-ransomware" scenario affecting all those shares... I'm using UNC routes for programs and desktop shortcuts for files.

Comment: Second the crypto. I'd suggest edit the batch to first remove the reg keys for known mapped drives, then ping the server first (we had an issue where it does not map the drive until it knows the IP, weird as but an issue on 10), then use Net Use with the FQDN.